# mySQL: How to filter columns which have no equal values in other table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables:

TABLE1

```
-----+--------+--------
id   +  uid1  +  .....
```

TABLE2

```
-----+--------+--------
id   +  uid2  +  .....
```

I need to find TABLE1 uid1 values (with theirs id) which absent in TABLE2 as uid2.

Comment: Please can give example with result ??

Comment: @esff See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and use it next time when asking a question then we don't have to make educated guesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, you just need to use `NOT IN` with a subquery that returns all uid2 values that are in table2.

This is how you query for it:

```
SELECT id, uid1 FROM table1 WHERE uid1 NOT IN 
(SELECT distinct uid2 FROM table2);
```

Comment: Pretty sure this query is useable for the topicstarter, but try to avoid answering on [half baked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -> *"Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which.are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."*